# The grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install in /target/

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

I have `windows 8.1` installed on SSD. Also I have multiple HDDs. 
I want to install Ubuntu 18 on a separate hard drive, while preserving the dual boot.

My device config looks like this

```
Device           Start         End     Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1           34      262177      262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2       264192 13468708863 13468444672   6.3T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  13468708864 15560144410  2091435547 997.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  15560144896 15628052479    67907584  32.4G Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048     616447     614400  300M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb2   616448     819199     202752   99M EFI System
/dev/sdb3   819200    1081343     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb4  1081344 1953523711 1952442368  931G Microsoft basic data

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 30283007 30280960 14.4G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *           63  102398309  102398247  48.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdd2       102398310 1953503999 1851105690 882.7G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdd5       102398373  409593239  307194867 146.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdd6       409593303 1953503999 1543910697 736.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 6 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Device      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sde1    2048    264191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sde2  264192 976773119 976508928 465.7G Microsoft basic data

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdf1  *         2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdf2          206848 102606847 102400000  48.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdf3       102606848 625139711 522532864 249.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

And `lsblk` output looks like this

```
sda               7.3T                               
├─sda1            128M                               
├─sda2 ntfs       6.3T                               Local Disk
├─sda3 ext4     997.3G   -> mount / there                               
└─sda4 swap      32.4G [SWAP]                        
sdb             931.5G                               
├─sdb1 ntfs       300M                               
├─sdb2 vfat        99M                               
├─sdb3            128M                               
└─sdb4 ntfs       931G                               
sdc              14.5G                               
└─sdc1 vfat      14.4G /cdrom                        UBUNTU 18_0
sdd             931.5G                               
├─sdd1 ntfs      48.8G                               
├─sdd2              1K                               
├─sdd5 ntfs     146.5G                               
└─sdd6 ntfs     736.2G                               
sde             465.8G                               
├─sde1            128M                               
└─sde2 ntfs     465.7G                               
sdf             298.1G                               
├─sdf1 ntfs       100M                               
├─sdf2 ntfs      48.8G                               
└─sdf3 ntfs     249.2G                               
sr0              1024M
```

I want to install Ubuntu 18 on my `ext4` partition (997GB). I mount `/` there (probably I should have freed some space for `/home` mount). And set `swap` 32GB (x2 of physical memory).

But for some reason during installation it fails with the error

```
The grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install in /target/. Without GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.
```

What is the problem? It also doesn't allow me to create another fat32 `efi` on the same HDD as linux installation.

P.s. for some reason my windows boot manager and windows installation on different HDDs but whatever.

Comment: @user68186 I tried to create it as /efi but it fails with the same error

Comment: @user68186 i tried `efi` type also but it fails too